# Prestashop 1.7.6.9 - Fatal Error in ProductListingPresenter::present()

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have an ecommerce made with Prestashop 1.7.6.9 that return often a 500 error.

So I've tried to enable the debug and now Prestashop show this error:

```
    (1/1) FatalThrowableError
    Type error: Argument 2 passed to 

    PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Product\ProductListingPresenter::present() 
    must be of the type array, boolean given, called in 
   /home/path/mywebsite.com/classes/controller/ProductListingFrontController.php on line 62
```

This error seem happens only when I open one category, that with debug mode show a message similar to this:

```
 [Debug] This page has moved
 Please use the following URL instead: https://mywebsite.com/it/17-category
```

when I try to open the version without lang selected: https://mywebsite.com/17-category

Have you got any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
> PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Product\ProductListingPresenter::present()
> must be of the type array, boolean given, called in
> /home/path/mywebsite.com/classes/controller/ProductListingFrontController.php on line 62

Your issue seems to be similar to this https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/16245

About this error

> [Debug] This page has moved
> Please use the following URL instead: https://mywebsite.com/it/17-category

In your BO > Shop Parameters > SEO & URLs page, you can disable the redirection by selecting this option
[image]

Thanks!

Best regards, Khouloud